# MATLAB and Armadillo, hints on translating

Tags: c++, matlab

i'm rewriting some Matlab code to c++ using [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#syntax), a libs for linear algebra. really good libs, IMHO. but i had to translate some matlab construct because armadillo isn't matlab.

i want to share my little snippet because i think there should be a better way (in terms of speed, mainly) to solve thoose little problems. i hope someone here could help me to improve my code!

```
static mat log(mat A) {
    /*
     * log function operates element-wise on matrix A
     * MATLAB code> log(A)
     */
    mat X(A);
    mat::iterator a = X.begin();
    mat::iterator b = X.end();

    for(mat::iterator i=a; i!=b; ++i) {
        (*i) = log(*i);
    }
    return X;
}
```

-

```
static mat vectorize(mat A) {
    /*
     * vectorise a matrix (ie. concatenate all the columns or rows)
     * MATLAB code> A(:)
     */
    mat B = mat(A);
    B.reshape(B.n_rows*B.n_cols, 1);
    return B;
}
```

-

```
static bool any(mat X, double n) {
    /*
     * check if there are some n in X
     * MATLAB code> any(X==n)
     * TODO: i'm not sure of description but it works for me
     */
    uvec _s = find(, n);
    if ( _s.is_empty() ) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

-

```
static double sum(mat X) {
    /*
     * sum a matrix
     * MATLAB code> sum(X)
     */
    return sum(sum(X))
}
```

-

```
static field<rowvec num2cell(mat X) {
    /*
     *  converts matrix X into field by placing each row of X into a separate row
     *  this method assume that a cell is a field<rowvec>, mayebe a template should be used to generalize..
     *  MATLAB code> num2cell(X)
     */
    field<rowvec> data1(X.n_rows,1);
for (uint r = 0; r < X.n_rows; ++r) {
    data1(r,0) = X.row(r);
}
    return data1;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

1. You're doing a copy in most of those snippets: if it was possible to do without a copy, it could be faster. Libraries such as Boost often offer two versions of a specific function: one which copies and another one which modifies in place.
2. `*i` is enough, you don't need `(*i)`:

   ```
   *i = log(*i);
   ```
3. This code:

   ```
   if ( _s.is_empty() ) 
       return true;
   else
       return false;
   ```

   can be written as:

   ```
   return _s.is_empty();
   ```

Answer (score 4):

For new users coming to this page, [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) has come a long way since 2012. All of these functions have native Armadillo implementations.

Armadillo has had [element-wise functions](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#misc_fns) since inception I think (someone please correct me): `log(A)`, `log2(A)`, and `log10(A)`:

```
using namespace arma;
// Generate a matrix with the elements set to random floating point values
// randu() uses a uniform distribution in the [0,1] interval 
mat A = randu<mat>(5,5);    // or mat A(5, 5, fill::randu);
mat B = log(A);
```

Added `any` and [vectorize](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#vectorise) in version 3.910:

```
vec V = randu<vec>(10);
mat X = randu<mat>(5,5);


// status1 will be set to true if vector V has any non-zero elements
bool status1 = any(V);

// status2 will be set to true if vector V has any elements greater than 0.5
bool status2 = any(V > 0.5);

// status3 will be set to true if matrix X has any elements greater than 0.6;
// note the use of vectorise()
bool status3 = any(vectorise(X) > 0.6);

// generate a row vector indicating which columns of X have elements greater than 0.7
urowvec A = any(X > 0.7);
```

Added [accu](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#accu) before version 4.6:

```
mat A(5, 6, fill::randu); // fill matrix with random values
mat B(5, 6, fill::randu);
double x = accu(A);
double y = accu(A % B);  // "multiply-and-accumulate" operation
                         // operator % performs element-wise multiplication
```

The `accu` function 'accumulates a sum', while the `sum` function generates a row or column vector that is the sum of the specified matrix dimension. For a column vector,
the sum of the elements is returned:

```
colvec v = randu<colvec>(10,1);
double x = sum(v);

mat    M = randu<mat>(10,10);

rowvec a = sum(M);
rowvec b = sum(M,0);
colvec c = sum(M,1);

double y = accu(M);   // find the overall sum regardless of object type
```

And Armadillo has its own [field](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#field) class template:

```
using namespace arma;
mat A = randn(2,3);
mat B = randn(4,5);

field<mat> F(2,1);
F(0,0) = A;
F(1,0) = B; 

F.print("F:");
F.save("mat_field");
```

Answer (score 3):

Cannot say much about the speed, but here are two observations:

- Your implementation of any appears to give true and false in the opposite way that Matlab would give them.
- If you want to mimic the n dimensional matrix sum in Matlab, the output should not be a number but a n-1 dimensional matrix. In case of a 'regular' matrix the output should be a vector.